# HTML form submission lead to blank page in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, .net, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a web application created on dot net 4.0 framework where UI is done with html pages.But recently we are facing issue on form submission on IE 11 browser.The moment we submit form it turn out to be blank page.For other browsers(Chrome,firefox),even lowers version of IE its working fine.

The interesting part of this issue is when I run the application on debug mode (by clicking f12) it just works fine.

Does anyone have idea  why this is happening?

```
<html>
<head>

<title>xyz</title>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
window.name = "__xyz_APP_WINDOW____";
// -->
</script>
<script language='JavaScript' src='scripts/adminmenu.js'></script>
<script language='JavaScript' src='scripts/utilities.js'></script>
<script language='JavaScript' src='scripts/toolTips.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/backoffice.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function checkFormData()
{
  do
  {
    var el = getForm().elements["uid"];
    if (!trimAll(el.value).length) break;
    el = getForm().elements["pwd"];
    if (!trimAll(el.value).length) break;
    getForm().elements["_tz_offset"].value = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset().toString();
    return true;
  } while(0);
  alert(errorMessage[el.name]);
  el.focus();
  return false;
}

var errorMessage = new Array();

errorMessage["uid"] = "Please enter a Login ID";
errorMessage["pwd"] = "Please enter a password";

function handleEnter(anElement)
{
  if (13 == self.event.keyCode)
  {
    if ("uid" == anElement.name)
    {
      anElement.form.elements["pwd"].focus();
    }
    else if ("pwd" == anElement.name)
    {
      if (checkFormData()) anElement.form.submit();
    }
    self.event.returnValue = false;
  }
}


//-->
</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="images/bkgd_BackOffice.gif" text="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" class="DetailBody" onLoad="getForm().elements['uid'].focus();">
<form name='adminForm' method='POST' onsubmit="return checkFormData()" >

  <input type="hidden" name="CurrentPage" value="admin_login"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="TargetPage" value="admin_index"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="_tz_offset" />
  <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#000000"><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images/masthead_BackOffice_OSP03.jpg" width="800" height="100"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr valign="top"> 
      <td align="center"> 
        <table width="60%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
          <tr> 
            <td> 
              <p class="h1">Back Office Login</p>
              <p>The Back Office is reserved </p>
                 <script type ="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
                     var correctBrowser = ((BrowserDetect.browser == "Safari" || BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome") && BrowserDetect.OS == "Mac") ||
                      ((BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" || BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome") && BrowserDetect.OS == "Windows");
                     //var correctBrowser = (BrowserDetect.browser == "Safari" && BrowserDetect.OS == "Mac") || (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.OS == "Windows");
                     var IsIE10OrIE11 =(BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.OS == "Windows" && (BrowserDetect.version=="10" || BrowserDetect.version=="11" ));
                     if (!correctBrowser) {

                         document.write('<p><b><font color="#CC3333">PLEASE NOTE:</font></b> you are currently using <b>' + BrowserDetect.browser + ' ' + BrowserDetect.version + '</b> on <b>' + BrowserDetect.OS + '</b>. The OrderStream Pro Back Office works best with <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/" target="_blank"><b>Chrome</b></a>.</p>');
                     }

                     if (IsIE10OrIE11) {
                         document.write('<p><b><font color="#CC3333">PLEASE NOTE :</font></b>  you are currently using <b>' + BrowserDetect.browser + ' ' +
                      BrowserDetect.version + '</b> on <b>' + BrowserDetect.OS + '</b>. This browser is not compatible for reporting tools but can be easliy made compatible.<a href="Instruction.htm" target="_blank"><b>Click here </b></a> to see the instruction for making it compatible. </p>');
                     }


// -->
    </script>

              <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                <!--vx_ErrorTextStart-->
                <tr> 
                  <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><b><font color="#CC3333">^vx_ErrorText^ </font></b></td>
                </tr>


                <!--vx_ErrorTextEnd-->
                <tr> 
                  <td align="right"><b>Login ID: </b></td>
                  <td > 
                    <input name="uid" maxlength="65" onFocus="select()" onKeyPress="handleEnter(this)" tabindex="1" style="width:120px;" value="^vx_uid^" size="10">
                  </td>
                   </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td align="right"><b>Password: </b></td>
                  <td> 
                    <input name="pwd" autocomplete="off" maxlength="65" onFocus="select()" type="password" onKeyPress="handleEnter(this)" style="width:120px;" size="10" tabindex="2">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td></td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:getPage('admin_forgot')">forgot 
                    your password?</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td></td>
                  <td> 
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="buttonBlue8pt" tabindex="4">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

          <td align="center">
          <div><iframe src="Footer.htm" frameborder="0" width="100%" ></iframe></div>
          </td>

          </tr>

        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<!--monitormarker-login-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please.

Comment: Try to share your code. It will be more helpful if you could make a reduced example that could be reproduced.

Comment: I have just added the html page in which form is submitted .

Comment: getForm () for getting document form  and trimAll() for removing  spaces from beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Do you have a DTD in your production code? Without DTD IE11 falls to IE9, and in that browser `console` doesn't exist if it's closed.

Comment: No we are not using DOCTYPE  on production.But I tried with DOCTYPE on html page,It didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure, if [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/IE/hh869299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is related?

Comment: I don't think so,as sometimes it works and sometimes don't on same machine.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this kind of issues is using the Developer Console in browser (in this case IE 11 by pressing F12).

Load the page in IE with open developer tools (F12) in Network tab (Ctrl+4). Don't forget to enable Network traffic capturing by clicking the Run button in top of the toolbar or simply hit the F5 key.

Double click on the URL with error and then see the response body for details.

Comment: also check the console in the F12 tools for any messages. My theory is the server-side is browser sniffing and cannot read the UA string correctly and does not return any content. If it works with the F12 tools open I would use Fiddler to check the network response that way.

Comment: But problem is that it works fine when developer tools is on.

Comment: I just checked the response in Fiddler,I am getting the response on form submission but some how response is getting buffered before delivering to the client and showing blank page.